# How to read specific chars and ints from file (update question)?

Tags: c, file, file-pointer

I have an input file:

```
H
3(3,3)
V
1(5,4)
2(7,7)
```

I am reading this with:

```
 12 FILE *fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
 13   if (fp == NULL)
 14   {
 15     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 16   }
 17   Stack* top = NULL;
 18   char gets[1024];
 19   while (fgets (gets, 1024, fp))
 20   {
 21     char node;
 22     int width = 0;
 23     int height = 0;
 24     int check = (sscanf (gets, " %c(%d,%d", &node, &width, &height));
 25     if (check == 1)
 26     {
 27       push(&top,node,0,0);
 28     }
 29     else if (check == 3)
 30     {
 31        push(&top,node,width,height);
 32     }
 33   }
 34   fclose (fp);
```

Which works fine.

```
  1 3(3,3)
  2 1(5,4)
  3 2(7,7)
  4 V
  5 H
```

But when I read something like this(input shortened as the file is big):

```
  1 93(11,16)
  2 11(12,33)
  3 H
  4 34(7,11)
  5 10(9,27)
  6 V
  7 32(12,30)
  8 30(12,16)
  9 41(12,19)
 10 H
 11 V
 12 50(12,13)
```

I get this, for example:

```
  1 9(0,0)
  2 1(0,0)
  3 H
  4 3(0,0)
  5 1(0,0)
  6 V
  7 3(0,0)
  8 3(0,0)
  9 4(0,0)
 10 H
 11 V
 12 5(0,0)
```

How can I fix this error to put the right output - so I get the proper value of a node instead of getting 9 instead of 93 for example.
Edit:
Its not working, I get something like this:

```
20 45(11,16)
 21 45(11,16)
 22 45(11,16)
 23 45(11,16)
 24 45(11,16)
 25 45(11,16)
 26 45(11,16)
 27 45(11,16)
 28 45(11,16)
 29 45(11,16)
 30 45(11,16)
 31 45(11,16)
 32 45(11,16)
 33 45(11,16)
 34 45(11,16)
 35 45(11,16)
 36 45(11,16)
 37 45(11,16)
 38 45(11,16)
 39 45(11,16)
 40 45(11,16)
 41 45(11,16)
 42 45(11,16)
 43 45(11,16)
 44 45(11,16)
 45 45(11,16)
 46 45(11,16)
 47 45(11,16)
```

which isnt even an input.

Comment: You will need to change `node` from `char` to a string (say `char tmp[32];`) and read into a temporary string with `" %[^(](%d,%d", tmp, &width, &height`, then you will check `isdigit(*tmp)` to determine if the 1st char in `tmp` is a digit or alpha-character. If digit, convert again with `sscanf`, if alpha, check length for the number of chars involved. The problem is you were going from reading a **single** character at the beginning to **multiple** characters.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you. Could you please post your code implmentation of this ?  I would greatly appreciate it as I am pretty lost now.

Comment: Sure, give me a sec, happy to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this iteration of your question, what is changed is instead of having only a single-character before the first `"("` or on a line by itself, you can now have multiple characters. You still want to be able to read either `'H'` or `93` as the first part of the line, so you need to adjust your *format-string* to read multiple character before the first `"("` and then either treat that as a string if it is an alpha-character, or convert it to an integer values if it is composed of digits. You can use something like:

```
#define MAXN   32
...
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        char tmp[MAXN];
        int node, width, height;
        switch (sscanf (buf, " %31[^(\n](%d,%d", tmp, &width, &height)) {
           ...
```

The format string being `" %31[^(\n](%d,%d"` where the `'\n'` is included in the *negated* character class along with `'('` to trim the `'\n'` from those lines that just contain a single character. The *circumflex* (e.g. `'^'`) at the beginning of the `[^..]` telling you to read character not including what is contained within the character class. (e.g. stop reading when the first negated character is encountered)

A full example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXN   32

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC];
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        char tmp[MAXN];
        int node, width, height;
        switch (sscanf (buf, " %31[^(\n](%d,%d", tmp, &width, &height)) {
            case 1 : printf ("single char/digit: '%s'\n", tmp);
                    break;
            case 3 : if (sscanf (tmp, "%d", &node) == 1)
                        printf ("all values: %d  %d  %d\n", node, width, height);
                    else
                        fputs ("error: parsing node from tmp.\n", stderr);
                    break;
            default : fputs ("invalid line format\n", stderr);
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

You can change the `switch()` statement to your `if/else` statements.

**Example Use/Output**

With your updated input, you would now get:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_sscanf_multival2 dat/multivals2.txt
all values: 93  11  16
all values: 11  12  33
single char/digit: 'H'
all values: 34  7  11
all values: 10  9  27
single char/digit: 'V'
all values: 32  12  30
all values: 30  12  16
all values: 41  12  19
single char/digit: 'H'
single char/digit: 'V'
all values: 50  12  13
```

Where you can push all value to your stack where needed. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. I will try to implement it later as I have to sleep now. Is there any way to ask you questions regarding this later on ?

Comment: Sure, just drop another comment here and I'll get it when you wake up `:)`

Comment: I have a question regarding the characters - you are storing it in a character array. Why do you do that when its only a single character? Edit : I guess my question is - if I have something like 3(3,3) does it go into the first swtich or second switch statement?

Comment: We do this because when we start reading the file we don't know if it will be `'H'` or `93`, so we read into a buffer sufficient to hold the longest integer value (that would be 22 char including the `'\0'` but the next power of 2 32 is sufficient and provides a few characters of wiggle-room). Once we check the return -- we know which it was and for "all values" we then convert the string to an integer by calling `sscanf` again and on success we can `push()` all 3 values as needed.

Comment: Now you are also free to attempt the read with two-separate `sscanf` statements, one with `" %c"` into some char and one with `"%d(%d,%d"` into 3 `int` variables. Try the `int` one first and it fails try the `char` next (which will read something, but you would need to check that is was a digit -- indicating something went wrong with the integer parse. In that case you end up validating the return from 2 separate `sscanf` to handle your initial parse of what do I have?. By reading the first value as a string, the return of the call to a single `sscanf` tells us what we have. OK either way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate you spending the time to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `int check = (sscanf (gets, " %c(%d,%d", &node, &width, &height));` and `char node;` with bit more complex lines:

```
int node = 0;
int check = (sscanf (gets, "%d(%d,%d", &node, &width, &height));
if (check == 0)
{
  char n = 0;
  check = sscanf(gets, " %c", &n);
  node = n;
}
```

Comment: I get this error:  error: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format=]
       check = sscanf(gets, "%c", &node);

Comment: I have edited my original post. It still doesnt work unfortunately.